# Which statistical test to use for comparing two groups?

Tags: statistics

I have data for 396 transcriptional factors (TF), where I have calculated the number of Transcriptional targets for each transcriptional factor present between the two groups:

Group-I(G-I): where co-exp genes have a correlation coefficient is more than 0.6 and

Group-II(G-II): where the co-exp genes have r values less than -0.6.

I have co-expression map for all the human transcription factors. My hypothesis is that transcriptional targets of a transcriptional factor are among the highly co-expressed gene for that transcription factor. For that, I have divided my group into high and low co-exp genes.

My question which statistical test I should use for evaluating the difference between the two groups?

```
  TF    G-I G-II
  AATF  1   0
  ABL1  5   1
  AES   0   1
  AHR   1   2
  AIP   2   0
 APBB1  0   1
APEX1   2   1
  AR    0   2
ARNT    3   0
```

Comment: Post a histogram or similar of the two groups, it would help to see if they have a particular distribution.